# How to set the number of auto-reconnect attempts of AWSIoTManager

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

How can I set the number of auto-reconnect attempts and retry limits of the AWSIoTManager?

here's the java example:

```
aWSIotMqttManager = AWSIotMqttManager(..)
aWSIotMqttManager.maxAutoReconnectAttempts = 1
aWSIotMqttManager.setReconnectRetryLimits(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the `aws-sdk-ios` you can provide each service with a configuration on registration (as shown with [AWSIoTManager](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSIoT/AWSIoTManager.h#L121))

`AWSServiceConfiguration` [inherits from](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Service/AWSService.h#L90) `AWSNetworkingConfiguration`, which in has the property [`maxRetryCount`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Networking/AWSNetworking.h#L159):

> The maximum number of retries for failed requests. The value needs to be between 0 and 10 inclusive. If set to higher than 10, it becomes 10.

For example (swift):

```swift
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(maxRetryCount: 7)
AWSIoTManager.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "USWest2IoTManager")
```

Comment: Is `maxRetryCount` should limit the number of auto-reconnect attempts after a connection error occurred?